# Concat 2D Arrays in f#

Tags: f#

How can I combine two 2d arrays generally?

My assumption (I could obviously easily test this) is that they always have the same number of columns:

```
let concatArrays (arr1:obj[,]) (arr2:obj[,]) = 
    ([arr1; arr2]) |> Array2d.concat
```

This function doesnt exist though. Just to be clear, the result should produce a 2d array with length = sum of lengths and same number of columns as the original arrays2D and should be the same type as the input, here obj[,]. I could obviously do this in a looping construct but I was wondering about an f# way. Thanks.

I tried this:

```
let append2D (arr1:float[,]) (arr2:float[,]) = 
    let cls = arr1.GetLength 1
    let rows1 = arr1.GetLength 0
    let rows2 = arr2.GetLength 0
    Array2D.init (rows1+rows2) cls (fun i j -> match i with | a when a <= rows1 -> arr1.[i,j] | _ ->  arr2.[i,j])
```

But this comes back with index out of bounds error.

Update of last row:

```
 Array2D.init (rows1+rows2) cls (fun i j -> if i < rows1 then arr1.[i,j] else arr2.[i,j])
```

**Update working solution:**

```
 Array2D.init (rows1+rows2) cls (fun i j -> if i < rows1 then arr1.[i,j] else arr2.[i-rows1,j])
```

thanks all

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2367927/969613) may help

Comment: Thanks. But doesnt this join multiple 1d arrays into one 2d array? what I want to do is join multiple 2d arrays into one 2d array. But maybe a good starting point. Or am I not getting it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can just use `Array.append`. If I am wrong, will you please provide an example input and output.

Comment: You may want to read this answer, and write your own function, or use an array of arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2367850/67566

Comment: @Bittenus: Array2D does not have append as far as I know

Comment: @Nik My bad. Mixed jagged and 2D arrays.

Comment: Use `<` instead of `<=` in your condition, or even cleaner:
`if i < rows1 then arr1.[i,j] else arr2.[i,j]`

Comment: @Bittenus: still getting same error. Do see anything else?

Comment: Yup: `arr2.[i,j]` should be `arr2.[i-rows1,j]` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following this [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367850/67566) here is a `concat` function for two equal column size `Array2D` arguments of any type `'a`:

```
let concat (a1: 'a[,]) (a2: 'a[,]) =
    let a1l1,a1l2,a2l1,a2l2 = (Array2D.length1 a1),(Array2D.length2 a1),(Array2D.length1 a2),(Array2D.length2 a2)
    if a1l2 <> a2l2 then failwith "arrays have different column sizes"
    let result = Array2D.zeroCreate (a1l1 + a2l1) a1l2
    Array2D.blit a1 0 0 result 0 0 a1l1 a1l2
    Array2D.blit a2 0 0 result a1l1 0 a2l1 a2l2
    result
```

You may check this experimentally, but it would have times better performance, than any variant based on `Array2D.init` because `Array2D.zeroCreate` and `Array2D.blit` implementations are highly optimized.

Answer (score 1):

@Gene has provided an excellent solution, using built-in blit function seems to be very useful in here.

I would like to post my usage of his function as an extension to the modules Array and Array2D for those who might find it useful:

```
 module Array = 
    let first (arr: 'a array) = arr.[0]
    let others (arr: 'a array) = arr.[1..]
    let split arr = first arr, others arr  

module Array2D = 
    let joinByRows (a1: 'a[,]) (a2: 'a[,]) =
        let a1l1,a1l2,a2l1,a2l2 = (Array2D.length1 a1),(Array2D.length2 a1),(Array2D.length1 a2),(Array2D.length2 a2)
        if a1l2 <> a2l2 then failwith "arrays have different column sizes"
        let result = Array2D.zeroCreate (a1l1 + a2l1) a1l2
        Array2D.blit a1 0 0 result 0 0 a1l1 a1l2
        Array2D.blit a2 0 0 result a1l1 0 a2l1 a2l2
        result

    let joinByCols (a1: 'a[,]) (a2: 'a[,]) =
        let a1l1,a1l2,a2l1,a2l2 = (Array2D.length1 a1),(Array2D.length2 a1),(Array2D.length1 a2),(Array2D.length2 a2)
        if a1l1 <> a2l1 then failwith "arrays have different row sizes"
        let result = Array2D.zeroCreate a1l1 (a1l2 + a2l2)
        Array2D.blit a1 0 0 result 0 0 a1l1 a1l2
        Array2D.blit a2 0 0 result 0 a1l2 a2l1 a2l2
        result

    // here joiner function must be Array2D.joinByRows or Array2D.joinByCols
    let joinMany joiner (a: seq<'a[,]>)  = 
        let arrays = a |> Array.ofSeq
        if Array.length arrays = 0 then 
            failwith "no arrays"
        elif Array.length arrays = 1 then 
            Array.first arrays
        else
            let rec doJoin acc arrays = 
                if Array.length arrays = 0 then
                    acc
                elif Array.length arrays = 1 then
                    joiner acc (Array.first arrays)
                else
                    let acc = joiner acc (Array.first arrays)
                    doJoin acc (Array.others arrays)
            doJoin <|| Array.split arrays
            // or doJoin arrays.[0] arrays.[1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rustam, Thanks for this. I was in need of these functions for working with excel ranges. After using these functions I found a few places for improvement.

First, rather than assuming that a1 and a2 have zero-based indexes, I recommend using the Array2D.base1 and Array2D.base2 for your indexes in the Array2D.blit functions. Note, it took me about 4 hours of pulling my hair out to figure out that this is what was causing some issues in my code.

i.e. for the joinByRows function:

```
Array2D.blit a1 (Array2D.base1 a1) (Array2D.base2 a1) result 0 0 a1l1 a1l2
Array2D.blit a2 (Array2D.base1 a2) (Array2D.base2 a2) result a1l1 0 a2l1 a2l2
```

Second, your joinMany function can be simplified significantly by using Seq.fold :

```
let joinMany joiner (a: seq<'a[,]>)  = 
        Seq.fold joiner (Seq.head a) (Seq.tail a)
```

I didnt check performance but I would imagine that the built in function would be more optimized.