# array concatenation in F#

Tags: f#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

Are there any analogs to Matlab's [horzcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)() and [vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html)() functions in F#? Because what I'm doing now seems asinine. There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367733/f-how-to-append-join-array2d-and-combine-1d-arrays-to-array2d) but it seems pretty dated.

```
    let arr = Array.init 5 (fun i -> 1.)
    let xMat = DenseMatrix.init l 2 (fun r c -> if c = 0 then 1. else arr.[r])
```

There is an Array.concat but it seems to work only vertically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function to do this for F# *arrays*, but in your code you are ultimately working with *matrices* from Math.NET Numerics and Math.NET has functions to append matrices vertically and horizontally:

```
let m1 = DenseMatrix.init 5 1 (fun _ _ -> 1.)
let m2 = DenseMatrix.init 5 1 (fun _ _ -> 2.)

DenseMatrix.append [m1; m2] // Append matrices horizontally
DenseMatrix.stack [m1; m2]  // Append matrices vertically
```

Comment: Excellent. These functions need to be more prominent in Math.NET tutorials.

Comment: @professorbigglesworth I agree that there could always be more/better  documentation. These two functions though are mentioned [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html). Also I frequently just dot into the object and explore what methods are available. I'm sure you could do a PR on GitHub to add your use case as an example doc. Or maybe a matlab to mathnet mapping.

Comment: @s952163 Thanks for pointing that out, somehow I missed it. On a side note, in my opinion Julia docs are the standard to follow. Perhaps something for the community to emulate. Everything methodically presented in one spot and searchable. [link](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/)

Comment: @professorbigglesworth I absolutely agree! The core library is well documented: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/fsharp-language-reference) but once you get into the various external libraries it can be a hit and miss.